# CSS Image Clipping

Tags: css

I have an image like this:

```
<img src="[path to image]" width="100%" class="clipthis" />
```

And my goal is to clip 10% from the right and the left. I have followed the various tutorials out there, but none seem to be able to do what I'm looking for. Is CSS clipping just not the answer for me?

```
.clipthis {  
  position: absolute;  
  clip-path: rect(100%, 10%, 100%, 10%);
}
```

Comment: so where is your CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `clip` and `clip-path` properties don't allow you to define the four coordinates as percentages:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-clip

Instead, try defining them with pixels:

EXAMPLE

```
.clipthis { 
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: rect(50px,50px,50px,50px);
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something obvious because this: http://jsfiddle.net/j52n1czz/  does not work.

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll instead of `clip-path` use `clip`. Also use a .jpg image instead of .svg.